# Express JS module.export is confusing me

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am learning express JS (EJS Templating engine) and used express-generator to create my project.
I have made just few changes in start-up code.

MyApp->routes->index.js

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

var c_index = require('../controllers/c_index');

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', c_index);

module.exports = router;
```

MyApp->controllers->c_index.js

```
var m_index = require('../models/m_index');

module.exports = function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('index', m_index);
};
```

MyApp->models->m_index

```
module.exports = function() {
  return { title: 'Express' };
};
```

MyApp->views->index.ejs

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title><%= title %></title>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='/stylesheets/style.css' />
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1><%= title %></h1>
    <p>Welcome to <%= title %></p>
  </body>
</html>
```

When I run this code chrome keeps loading and when I close browser I get,

```
GET / - - ms - -
```

When I edit MyApp->controllers->c_index.js as,

```
res.render('index', m_index());
```

It Works.
It is confusing me because,

```
router.get('/', c_index);
```

Does not have brackets. but,

```
res.render('index', m_index());
```

Have brackets.
My question is why one is with no brackets but other is having it?
Although,

```
router.get('/', c_index(req, res, next));
```

is not working.
Please help me. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

`m_index` is a module that looks like this:

```
module.exports = function() {
  return { title: 'Express' };
};
```

So when you do something like `const m_index = require('m_index')`, `m_index` is a function.

To call a function, you use parentheses. `m_index()` calls the function called `m_index` and returns the result.

`c_index.js` also exports a function.

`res.render(..., m_index())` looks like that because `res.render` wants to be passed an object, not a function. So you call the function, get an object as a result, and pass that into `res.render`.

`router.get(..., c_index)` looks like that because `router.get` wants to be passed a function, so you shouldn't call it yourself.

Comment: Thank you for your response. as far as i know both are returning object right?

Comment: Both what? The functions `m_index` and `c_index`? I'm not sure what `c_index` returns. (It returns whatever `res.render` does... possibly nothing.)

Answer (score 0):

When you call `res.render('index', m_index());`  you are making a response call to render a view by calling the view which is `'index'` then you call a locals object, `m_index`

It follows this syntax below and more information can be found here  [res.render()](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res.render)

```
res.render(view [, locals] [, callback])
```

---

Next, in your second question, you are asking about two different calls

1. router.get('/', c_index);
2. res.render('index', m_index());

Your first call is a path `'/'` and callback `c_index` object using get applying this syntax.   Check out the examples here where more can be answered here [router.METHOD](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#router.METHOD).

```
router.METHOD(path, [callback, ...] callback)
```

And your second call here is follows the same paradigm as mentioned above

```
res.render('index', m_index());
```

In trying to understand what your are calling with m_index and c_index try using the the [typeof](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof) operator.  Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Change it with SMVC, hope it will help you start a contructure in nodejs.

**app.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

var index = require('../routes/index');

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', index);

module.exports = router;
```

**In routes/index.js**

```
var SomeController = require('../controllers/SomeController');

module.exports = function (express) {
    var router = express.Router();
    var someController = new SomeController ;
    router.get('/', someController.yourAction);
    return router;
}
```

**In controllers/SomeController.js, [You could use ES6 with Class](http://es6-features.org/)**

```
class SomeController {
    yourAction(req, res, next) {
        // Do something. Use Model & Service if you want to work with DB
        res.render('/home', {hi: "Hello guy ^^"});
    }
}
module.exports = SomeController;
```

**In home.hbs (or home.ejs...) - I suggest you use .hbs with template engine. [See more](http://handlebarsjs.com/)**

> With hbs: {{hi}}
>
> With ejs: <%= hi %>

**Do you have any questions? Please comment, I can help you much...**

Comment: Thank you for your response. I really like your way to do it. but I have one question. I am using mysql (because of lots of experience with it). I want to ask that why not your approach contain models? I mean database part can be separated in model file.

Comment: Create 2 folder: models and serives. It will work with us. **In the controller (SomeController), you need require Model and use it. It is SMVC.**
**1. Model:** You want to use MySQL, so we will use ORM + Node. See more: [link](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/). Create Model Schema into here.
**2. Services:** We use it when you want get/set/... with DB

Comment: With MySQL + Node + ORM: I suggest you install package [sequelizejs](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/)